# Reference Cell using its address

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to figure out some google sheets magic and I hope you could be a help to me.

I've got 2 sheets:

- [Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmh1s.png) is a table of all possible combinations of my data.
- In [Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENXk1.png) I use data from sheet 1 to make custom combinations of that data.

In Sheet 2 I have address of cell from Sheet 1 of place that my data cross.

Now I want to populate the sheet 1 with Names of the Combinations (like *Dagger*, *Sword*), so i can easily check if the combination is already used or which combination is not used at all.

To find the address i use the formula `=ADDRESS(MATCH(D4;Sheet1!$2:$2;0);MATCH(C4;Sheet1!$B:$B;0); 4)`

EDIT:
You can check you the example sheet in under this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HMPNd_FzI07YpHFCZLv79yseciZMKQyqpw-KuOpPRZk/edit?usp=sharing)

I can even give you the pseudo code that I would use in any programming language in this situation:

```
//This is code for cells C3:X30 in Sheet1:
for each CELL in SHEET2:
  if this.adress == CELL.TEXT
    this.TEXT += getCell(CELL.COLUMN, 1).TEXT + ' ,'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your spreasheet, so we can try and help you?

Comment: Yes, This is the Minimum, reproducible example: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HMPNd_FzI07YpHFCZLv79yseciZMKQyqpw-KuOpPRZk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `Here I want a list of Combinations From Sheet 2 that has this adress of the cell` what combinations? What cells? Your sheet is entirely blank of data which makes it harder to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: @RodrigoBiffi, I'm sorry, I've updated the sheet, and also edited the question and added Pseudo code, if this helps.
The Sheet1 is now filled with example as I want it to behave automatically. 
Cells C3:X30 are filled with Names of combinations from Sheet 2 (i.e. NAME 1, NAME 2). 
Every cell in columns named "Address" in Sheet 2 has address to specific cell in Sheet1. In the cell in Sheet1 with the address specified in Sheet 2 I want to make a list of Names that correspond to this address (same column, row 1).

Comment: I still don't follow, sorry. I'm not sure what you want to be inserted into the cells in Sheet 1. You have NAME 1, NAME 2, NAME 3 but also dropdowns for `triger` and `effect`, can you give an example of what one row in Sheet 2 would say, and what that would correspond to in Sheet 1?

Comment: In `Sheet 1` I have a list of all Triggers in `Column B`, and list of all Effects in `Row 2`.
In `Sheet 2` I have Trigger and Effect that I choose from the list of all possible effects and triggers (dorpdowns takes values from Column B and Row 2 in Sheet 1).
After I select both of them i get the address of the cell in Sheet 1 that is the cross of that trigger with that effect. 
Now I want to fill that exact address with name from Sheet 2. So if under `Name 1` I have row : C3 (Address), 1 (Trigger), A (Effect) that means that I want to have `Name 1` in Cell C3 in Sheet 1.

Comment: Can there be potentially more than one name per cell?

Comment: Yes there is, and this is the information I'm most interested in, because then I will know what combination of `trigger` and `effect` is used most and what isn't used at all.